# Explicit constructor call

Tags: c++

I'm wondering if there is some sort of trick to explicitly call a constructor using object pointer. If that was a legal syntax it would look like this:

```
Foo *p = malloc( sizeof(Foo) );

p->Foo::Foo();
```

P.S. I do know that I can do `Foo *p = new Foo();` but there is a serious reason for using malloc() explicitly.

Comment: @John: I'd like to know this reason you are talking about :), `new` is probably using `malloc` under the hood, so why bother ?

Answer (score 17):

You can use the "placement new" operator for this:

```
Foo *buf = malloc( sizeof(Foo) );
Foo *p = new (buf) Foo();
```

Comment: Don't forget if you manually construct it you should also manually destroy it.

Comment: Should note also that in this case you're also responsible for explicitly calling the destructor: `p->~Foo();`  (`delete p` will not work).

Answer (score 9):

Use **placement new**:

```
Foo* p = new(malloc(sizeof(Foo))) Foo;
```

(ommitting any out-of-memory checks here)

Basically, `new(address) Foo()` constructs an object of type `Foo` in the location pointed to by `address`, in other words: it invokes the constructor.

Answer (score 3):

You can construct new object at some address using placement new.

```
void *buf = malloc(sizeof(Foo)); 
Foo *p = new (buf) Foo();
```

You can read more at [wikipedia's article about it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_syntax)

Answer (score 3):

Others have already pointed out that you can use placement new. This works well if you want certain, specific objects of a class to be in memory allocated with `malloc`. As has also been pointed out, when you do this, you need to invoke the dtor explicitly.

If you want *all* objects of a class to be in memory allocated with `malloc`, you can overload `operator new` (and `operator delete`) for that class, and have them call `malloc` to get the raw memory. This relieves client code of the extra steps of separate allocation/initialization.

If you want all objects in a collection (or more than one collection) to be in memory allocated with `malloc`, you can supply an allocator to the collection to make that happen. Again, this relieves client code of dealing with the allocation, and lets the container look, act, and "feel" like a normal container.

Answer (score 0):

```
    struct MyClass
    {
            MyClass()
            {
                    std::cout << "ctor" << std::endl;
            }
            ~MyClass()
            {
                    std::cout << "dtor" << std::endl;
            }
    };

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
            // Allocate memory and call constructor
            MyClass myObj;

            // Call constructor again with placement new
            new (&myObj) MyClass;
    }
```